# Is the use of JavaScript for cryptography ever appropriate in the browser?

Tags: cryptography, javascript, web-browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How secure is aSSL (javascript)? Does it effectively mimic SSL?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24423/how-secure-is-assl-javascript-does-it-effectively-mimic-ssl)

After some searching around, I realized we don't have an easily visible canonical question about this on IT.SE, and [new questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25609/sending-data-form-registration-forms) still ask about it in passing. It's referenced in comments [elsewhere](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7975/is-a-javascript-implementation-of-aes-any-less-secure-than-other-language-implem), but I haven't been able to find a dedicated question and answer on this point. Most site regulars will know of [Matasano's essay](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/) on the topic. Therefore:

**Is it ever appropriate to implement browser cryptography in JavaScript rather than use TLS?**

Comment: There are certainly niche uses for crypto in JS. But it is never a substitute for protecting the parent connection with TLS, due to the trust-bootstrapping problem.